# UITextView text get cut off

Tags: ios, uitextview

[In iOS 10 Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaTPn.png) uitextview's text is cut off ,but it is perfectly working [In iOS 9 devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlEHm.png).
The text that is cut off is limited to certain length.Is anyone also encountering this issue??

Comment: can you show screen shot or else ...

Comment: the text is cut off at certain length.The problem is only in iOS 10 devices

Comment: You need to provide more information. Otherwise moderators will remove your question. Regards